# Ajax form with Express res.download and BlockUI not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

I build a server with Express for user to upload images ,then server process images array and response a zip by res.download .

First ,I try to post the Html form with submit function,it can work.

But I wish to **display an image when the data process on the browser** ,  so I use BlockUI.

And turn to **use ajax send the form** ,when it success will **unblokUI** , **download file** , then **turn to other page**.

Now server also get the ajax and sent response ,but it doesn't download the file.

Anyone has any idea?  I'll be very appreciate!!

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" action="url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>upload</h2>
    <div>
        <label>User：</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" accept="text" required="required">
    </div>
    <input id="fileUpload" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" multiple="" required="required">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.blockUI({ message: '<img style="width:50%" src="img_path' });
        var form_data = new FormData($('form')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url',
            data: form_data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,

            success: function() {
                $.unblockUI();
                location.replace("url");
            }
        });
```

**Node js**

```
app.post('router', upload.array('file', 30),function(req, res) {　
    compressing.zip.compressDir(myfile_path).then(() => { 
        res.download(myfile)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's totally work dude,

express `index.js` file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.post('/download', function (req, res) {
    res.download("./test.zip")
})
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

`test.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
  url:"http://localhost:3000/download",
  method:"POST",
  type:"POST",
  xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
  },
  success:function(response, status, xhr){
    var fileName = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split("=")[1]
    console.log(fileName)
    var a = document.createElement('a');
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
});

  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

place your `test.html` file on static folder beside `index.js` file.
also download `jquery.js` and place beside test.html file.

Comment: Hello @mahradbt ,sorry I'm new with jquery .
Did you mean I test the code in ajax success?

Comment: first, send the request with `postman`.  if you can download file, use `$.fileDownload` instead of `$.ajax`

Comment: Hello @mahradbt ,I follow your tips to sent request by postman . Response looks good ,it return back a { content-type →application/zip },and name also correct. 
So I use fileDownload like this 
$.fileDownload({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'url',
                data: form_data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function() {
                    // $.unblockUI();
                }
            });

But it didn't sent request to server.

Comment: wait I test an example

Comment: Hello @mashradbt I tried the code, but it displayed  
   xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition') is null  
even I do       res.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename" + filename)     it also displayed same error

Comment: @JSU test the new code. don't forget check and upvote buddy ;)

Comment: @masradbt it can work right now , Thanks a lot mate , you let me can enjoy my weekend.